# evenly spaced tick markers

Tags: java, graphics, graph, modulo

I have to draw tick markers at 10 percent intervals starting at zero and going to 100 percent of the width of a graphical object.

I would do something like:

```
int width = 556;
int k = width/10;
for(int i = 0;i<width;i++){
    if(i%k==0){
        draw marker on gui indicating a ten percent increment (10,20,etc. up to 100%)
    }
}
```

The problem, as you can see, is that 100% will be marked at index 550, which is 6 indices before the actual end.  This is, of course, unacceptable.

Also, of course, the actual numerical value of the width is a variable that will change.

Can anyone show me how to alter the code above so that it evenly spaces the markers and also places the 100% marker at the end?

If I simply delete the tenth marker and manually place a marker at 100%, the spaces between the markers will not be even.  There must be a better way of doing this, so I am hoping someone can show me.

Comment: Why make it so complicated? You know where the first marker goes. The second one goes how much farther down the line? And the third? (And assuming your loop starts at 0, the third marker has index 2...and 2 times what amount is what you're looking for?)....etc.

Comment: @Bart , I know where the first one goes.  I know where the last one goes.  I know the remainder of 6 in the example I gave above.  What I do not know is how to efficiently distribute the remainder among the remaining tick marks so that the tick marks are evenly placed, remembering that the remainder will be a variable. Can you be more specific in what you mean?  +1 for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who offered suggestions.  The solution I ended up using was something I came up with myself, which was to control the dimensions of the rectangle so that the width and height are integer multiples of the tick mark spacings.  That way, I do not have to shuffle remainders around.  Instead, I have the buffer space around the rectangle take up whatever the remainder might be with each resizing of the frame.  Since the rectangle dimensions themselves are always integer multiples of the tick mark spacing, there is no longer any problem with odd-looking spacings of tick marks.

Thanks again to everyone.  I just added extra +1 points to each person who tried to help.

Answer (score 3):

Use doubles for decimal places.
Don't go through all the mod operations. Do a simple loop of 10 iterations, one for each marker:

```
    int width = 556;
    double dist = ((double)width)/9.0;
    double k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        // Draw marker at (int)k
        k += dist;
    }
```

Comment: won't that leave me with the same problems of the remainder, and uneven spacing? +1 for trying to help.

Comment: No, it won't. Since you're using a double, you'll have decimal places. You didn't before because you were using an int. For this reason, you got an error during runtime. However, if you draw the marker at k, casting it to an int as you go along, you will be able make evenly-spaced tick marks. Try it in your program. In principle, it should work.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that since you're shuffling remainders like this, the ticks might still appear unevenly spread to the eye. To remedy this, you can i.e. use antialiased lines and draw them at decimal values.

Comment: @eboix , Another +1 for both of you because you gave me thoughtful suggestions.  I ended up doing something different, which I describe in the answer I just posted myself.